# Why this options get not values on load?

Tags: angularjs

i do have two selects with several values but on load it can't get the value of a selected item onload..

```
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':NewRequest.IdTeam.$invalid}">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-4 control-label"> Team:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select ng-required='!Template.IdTask' class="form-control" ng-change="Template.IdTask=null" name="IdTeam" ng-model="Template.IdTeam" ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in Groups"> </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':NewRequest.IdTask.$invalid}">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-4 control-label"> Task:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select ng-required='!Template.IdTeam' class="form-control" ng-change="Template.IdTeam=null" name="IdTask" ng-model="Template.IdTask" ng-options="a.id as a.Title for a in ListTask"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When i do this it return the value

```
<h3 class="modal-title">Edit Email Template{{Template.IdTeam}}</h3>
```

THIS is my Modal opening and my controller

```
$scope.open = function (item) {
    item.Group = $scope.Groups;
    item.Task = $scope.Task;

    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'EditEmailTemplate.html',
        controller: 'EditEmailTemplateController',
        resolve: {
            Request: function () {
                return item;
            }
        }
    }).result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        loadData();
    });
};


var EditEmailTemplateController = function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $modalInstance, $modal, Request, $upload, FormField) {
$scope.FormField = FormField;
$scope.Template = Request;
```

});

EditModal Look like this

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="EditEmailTemplate.html">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button ng-click="cancel()" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
    <h3 class="modal-title">Edit Email Template{{Template.IdTeam}}</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form name="NewRequest" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':NewRequest.IdTeam.$invalid}">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-4 control-label"> Team:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select ng-required='!Template.IdTask' class="form-control" ng-change="Template.IdTask=null" name="IdTeam" ng-model="Template.IdTeam" ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in Groups"> </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':NewRequest.IdTask.$invalid}">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-4 control-label"> Task:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select ng-required='!Template.IdTeam' class="form-control" ng-change="Template.IdTeam=null" name="IdTask" ng-model="Template.IdTask" ng-options="a.id as a.Title for a in ListTask"></select>
            </div>
        </div>....
```

Comment: what does EditEmailTemplate.html look like?

Comment: I ask because this:

    `<h3 class="modal-title">Edit Email Template{{Template.IdTeam}}</h3>`

has to come from somewhere.  Where is that html?

Comment: i do this just because i want to display it on the title but it doesn't work for the select